# Add More Button, to add a row at bottom of table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have table like this:

```
<table id="myTable" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>Name</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input name="field-1" type="text" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input name="field-2" type="text" /></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I want a ADD MORE button, so every time when we click ADD MORE button it adds a new row with unique NAME like

```
<tr><td><input name="field-3" type="text" /></td></tr>
<tr><td><input name="field-4" type="text" /></td></tr>
```

Please suggest a solution.

Thanks you!

Answer (score 2):

```
$('button#add_more').on('click', function() {
    var table = $('table#myTable tbody'),
        len = $('input[type=text]', table).length;
  table.append('<tr><td><input name="field-'+ (len+1)+'" type="text" /></td></tr>');
})
```

​

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xFmHw/5/)**

Comment: @PerminderSinghKlair welcome, if any answer helps you, you should accept that and this is the best way to thanks an answerer.

Answer (score 0):

Demo :: http://jsfiddle.net/ankur20us/MTXhZ/

```
$('#click').click(function(){
    var totRows=$('#myTable tr').length;

    $('#myTable').append("<tr><td><input name='field-"+ totRows +"' type='text' /></td></tr>")

});​
```